# 2 tables of contents : one with page numbers and one without

Tags: table-of-contents

I'd like to have a document with two table of contents. One at beginning and one at the end.

The first would be without dots and pages numbers.

The second would be traditional with dots and pages numbers (like with `\tableofcontents`).

How can do I this in an `article`?

Answer (score 2):

[`etoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoc) allows you to use multiple `\tableofcontents` within the same document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoc}% So you can use multiple \tableofcontents in one document

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nopagetableofcontents}{{%
  \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}% Remove dots leader
  \let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
  \renewcommand{\contentsline}[3]{\oldcontentsline{##1}{##2}{}}% Remove page number
  \tableofcontents
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nopagetableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

In the above example, `\nopagetableofcontents` removes the dots leader by setting a large value for `\@dotsep` and removes the page number by redefining the way `\contentsline{<type>}{<heading>}{<page number>}` works, replacing it with the same function that ignores the `<page number>` argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very great solution for me. Thanks again.  Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `memoir` class (covers `book`, report`and`article` outputs).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter} % no page numbers for chapters
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
% similarly for other divisions
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{First}
\section{Sec 1}
Some text

\chapter{Second}
\section{Sec 2}
More text

\clearpage
\cftpagenumberson{chapter} % page numbers for chapters
\cftpagenumberson{section}
% etc
\tableofcontents*

\end{document}
```

See section 9.2 *The class ToC methods* in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`). The starred version of `\tableofcontents` is to prevent the ToC being listed in the ToC.

To use `memoir` to get `article` class output:

```
\documentclass[article,...]{memoir}
```

and in the document `\chapter` will be set as `\section`, `\section` as `\subsection` etc. Thus if you ever need to reset your article style as `report` or `book` just use \documentclass[...]{memoir}.

See **Chapter 1 Starting off** in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`).

Comment: hello thanks for your help. Sorry, it's not what I'm looking for, I need article class. Best regards

Comment: @loruyza I have edited my answer to say how to use `memoir` to get `article` style output.